# How do i check if a exchange connection is valid? (via ews)

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I need a way to figure out if an via user input configured exchange connection is valid.
I use ews.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Use Autodiscovery if its available.
- If you know the url, check the web service exists by creating a HttpWebRequest with the EWS URL and use HTTPWebResponse to check that the status of the response is valid.
- If you want to test an actual web service call on a mailbox, you could try finding the root folder using the GetFolderType call.